# Same timestamp orderBy

Tags: sql, database, laravel

Good day,

I am trying to get the latest value in a database. I can't do it by ID because if they change the company the abbr would change but the created time would be updated to that time so i can get the latest by time. But when adding a company 10 people can add it at the exact same time throwing off the time.

```
$latest = DB::table('inventories')->where('company', $request->company)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->first();
```

But let's say 5 people added an item same exact time. How do i get the latest value even if the time is exact.

Five of the time would be 2019-08-23 17:33:18

Example:

```
LL1001 2019-08-23 17:33:18
LL1002 2019-08-23 17:33:18
LL1003 2019-08-23 17:33:18
LL1004 2019-08-23 17:33:18
```

When i run the query i would get LL1002 instead of LL1004. The number is always going to be higher for the latest time. And this field in the DB is unique so it gives an error saying duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Just order by Id column after you ordered by time.

```
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
```